# js split array add space

Tags: javascript, split

I have string

```
var myString = 'Hello word Sentence number';
```

I need make array like `["Hello ","word ","Sentence ","number "]`
with space after words, I did `myString.split(/(?= )/);`
but I received `["Hello"," word"," Sentence"," number"]`
How to make that space was after words?

I get this line during the event "keyup" the space is a sign that the word over and it can be compared. I don't need .trim()

Comment: May I ask why you want to retain the spaces?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it using just the `split` function.  Your example is a little unclear because you add a space to the last element, `number`, even though there's not a space after it in your original string.  You can always just loop through the array and manually add a space to each element.

Comment: there is no space after the word 'number' but in the resulting array the word is followed by a space as well ... is that what you want ? if so you could split your string and then use the 'map' function on the result to append a space to all strings.

Comment: I have another array with spaces and I compare with it

Comment: @SvetlanaKonstantinovnaIvanni maybe try getting rid of all the spaces in both arrays using `.trim()` that way you don't have to worry about the spaces at all...

Comment: I get this line during the event "keyup" the space is a sign that the word over and it can be compared. I don't need .trim()

Comment: @SvetlanaKonstantinovnaIvanni : have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you were after, but you can split on word boundaries using the regex token \b. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/930xy5b7/

```
myString.split(/\b/);
```

Comment: This produces elements for each space, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @mittmemo it might be maybe the OP didn't realize this was an option.  I would recommend stating that in your answer CodeHunter...

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't quite work does it. Ah well, it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

A foreach loop to go through each item in the array would work:

`

```
var myString = 'Hello word Sentence number';
var myStringArray = myString.split(" ");

myStringArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry += " "
});
```

`

more on foreach: [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can go back after splitting and "manually" add a space to each word, like this:

```
var myString = 'Hello word Sentence number';
var splitArray = myString.split(" ");

for(var x = 0; x < splitArray.length; x++){
  splitArray[x] = splitArray[
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, you could use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
//this is what you've done
var myString = 'Hello word Sentence number';
var arr = myString.split(/(?= )/);

//this will add a space in the end of every string of the array
var arrWithSpaces = $.map( arr, function(el){
  return el + " ";
});
```

Or, as suggested, use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you're not using jquery:

```
//this is what you've done
var myString = 'Hello word Sentence number'; 
var arr = myString.split(/(?= )/);

//this will add a space in the end of every string of the array
var arrWithSpaces = arr.map( function(el){ 
    return el + " "; 
});
```

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.map`, and leave jQuery out of this.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 map function:

```
const myString = 'Hello word Sentence number';
const splitString = myString.split(' ').map(el => `${el} `);
console.log(splitString);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.